# How to set up a Quiz game with multiple types of questions? (Structs and DataTables)

Tags: unreal-4, data-structure

I am looking to integrate a quiz mode into a game I am in the process of developing in Unreal Engine 4. I'm really just kind of stuck on how to set up my data structures and not really know the way to go about doing it. At least for now I want the quiz to contain two different types of questions but, it could possibly contain more types later on.

The first type of question is a simple multiple choice type of question that contains a string Question, a string array of answers, and an integer for the correct index of the answer.

The second type of question I have is basically a click on the correct component that is in the scene already and then click on a confirm button to submit the response. It contains a string question and an integer id and string name for the answer. I haven't decided yet on which route I want to go with regarding the item id vs. item name.

Basically, what I really want is a single data table for all of my questions that I can choose a question at random from. My main question is, is there a way to create a single data table with these requirements? I mean I know I could just kind of merge the two and have empty fields in my data table but, maybe is there a way to basically have an enum within the data table to choose between what type of question I want on this particular row?

I know I have stated a few possibilities on how I can set up the data table but, I would really like some feed back on if there are different ways other than what I have stated already. I mean it doesn't even have to be a data table, if there is a more efficient way to go about doing this I am all for it. The main goal is to only have one main data structure to pull my questions from.

Comment: This looks like a job for inheritance. Base class Question, two others inherit. They all have a numerical ID, pick the ID at random, then get the right one with a query of some sort.

Comment: @Almo I didn't think that structs could use inheritance, at least in Unreal anyway.

Comment: I'm not talking about `struct`. Why does `struct` matter?

Comment: I just checked, yes they can. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979211/struct-inheritance-in-c

Comment: @Almo it matters because I am trying to create a datatable in unreal and it requires a struct. From what I can tell looking at the struct BP there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. I don't think Unreal allows it. Its probably using an older version of C++

Comment: structs and classes are very, very similar. If there's an issue, it's with blueprints, not C++.